# Spring boot. Как получить данные из поля input и потом умножить их с данными из базы данных?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Есть вопрос, как вывести данные из динамической формы, которая в зависимотри от того сколько элементов в БД создает полей input. Т.е есть поля которые создаются автоматически и надо получить числа которые будут вписанны туда.

Пытался выводить через объект но ничего не выходит.

Вот код динамической формы.

```
<form action="/" method="post"  th:object="${Elements}">
    <div th:each="el : ${elementsGet}">
        <h3 th:text="${el.name}"/>
        <input type="text" name="value" th:placeholder="${el.value}">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Код контроллера

```
@GetMapping("/")
    public String main(Model model) {
        Iterable<Elements> elements = elementsRepo.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("elementsGet", elements);
        return "main";
    }

    @PostMapping("/")
    public String getElements(@ModelAttribute("Elements") Elements elements,  Model model) {

        System.out.println(elements.getValue().toString());

        return "main";
    }
```

Comment: Нужен th:field на inputе, чтоб указать поле в Elements куда будут добавляется значение инпута, это поле должно быть листом String

Comment: Контроллер может принимать только значения элементов, а не сами элементы, для которых требуется конвертация типов.